# If we know the congruence of the apex and the base of two isosceles, are both congruent triangles? (help with the proof)

Tags: geometry, triangles

Well, there are general criteria for congruence of triangles:

- SAS (Side-Angle-Side)
- ASA (Angle-Side-Angle)
- SSS (Side-Side-Side)
- SAA (Side-Angle-Angle)

And there are some criteria for specific triangles:

- SSA (Side-Side-Angle) The side in front of the angle doesn't have to be minor of the adjacent one
- HC (Hypotenuse-Cathetus) In a right triangle
- HA (Hypotenuse-Angle) In a right triangle

And my question is about one case that I know is true in Euclidean geometry (which I would call AB—Apex-Base—):

> If two isosceles triangles have in common the apex and the base, both are congruent

It's "obvious" but the proof is not that obvious. Here's my attempt.

---

### Proof

Let △ABC and △A'B'C' be isosceles triangles like the next figure [image: Two isosceles triangles with the same apex and base]

Now, if AB = A'B' both triangles are congruent by SAS, but suppose that's not the case. Without loss of generality assume that AB<A'B', thus it's possible to mark a point D' in A'B' such that A'D' = AB, likewise it's possible to mark a point E' in A'C' such that A'E' = AC. Join the points D'E' to form the △A'D'E' ≅ △ABC by SAS.

[image]

Then we must conclude that D'E' = B'C', but this is a contradiction since D'E'<B'C', so assuming  AB ≠ A'B' is absurd, hence AB = A'B' which derives △ABC ≅ △A'B'C' Q.E.D.

---

That's what I did, but I feel that the contradiction is not fully handled, especially because I cannot find another argument but visual that D'E' < B'C'.
As I mentioned before, I know this is true in Euclid's (plane) geometry. I'm more interested in a proof (if exist) avoiding parallels (or equivalently the constant sum of the measures of the angles of any triangle), so that the result would be a neutral geometry like the SAA criterion (https://www.jstor.org/stable/27960835?seq=1).

Or I'm trying to prove a result that's not neutral geometry that in some cases D'E' =B'C'?

---

### Edit

Thanks for your answers, they are very useful. But up this moment all of them depends on the parallel postulate which I try to avoid in order to find out if this is a neutral geometry result.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the sum of angles in a triangle are $180^\circ$, then, if the apex has value $A$, the other two angles are $90^\circ-A/2$. Then the problem is reduced to the angle-side-angle case. The side is the base.

In your case you use the same angles to show $D'E'||B'C'$. Then the triangles are similar, and the ratio of the sides is equal to the ratio of the bases. You **know** that the bases are the same, so then the sides must be the same. The problem is then reduced to side-side-side case.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is correct - good job there.

An easier way to see this is the following:

1. You have an isoceles triangle, so $\angle ABC=\angle ACB$ (for both).
2. You know $\angle BAC=\angle B'A'C'$ (by hypothesis).
3. Angles add up to $180^{\circ}$, so $\angle ABC=\angle A'B'C'=90^{\circ}-\angle BAC$.
4. Therefore, $\triangle ABC$ is similar to $\triangle A'B'C'$.
5. You additionally know that length $BC=B'C'$.

Well, they're now congruent (by SAA or equivalent).